# How to filter nested Collections with values inside an array with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get a Collection filtered by the category "free-content".

[image]

I tried to select the column and use the whereIn method:

```
$collection = Entry::query()
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->select('data.items')
            ->whereIn('categories', ['free-content']);
    })
    ->get();

    dd($collection);
```

Comment: provide input and expected output

Comment: @ericmp the input is in the picture. I have two entries with two different categories, 'paid-content' and 'free-content'. I just want to query the entry with "free-content" category you see picture.

Comment: provide input and expected output via txt, not img

Comment: Welcome to SO Eugen. Starting from the Entry model and working towards a category filter seems a bit backwards, have you tried directly filtering by the Category model, then fetching the entries for that category?

Comment: @Mike thank you mike, this was the right hint! now its working!

Comment: @ericmp sorry! I will do next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, thank you for the hint @Mike. Its easier than I thought :)

```
$collection = Entry::query()
        ->where('collection', 'modules')
        ->whereTaxonomy('categories::free-content')
        ->get();
```